# Some LED lights on the circuit fail to turn on while others do not

Tags: led

We have two sets of LED ceiling lights. One stays on, the other (*which has three lights*) looks like it's pulsing turning ever so slightly on then dimming to off repeatedly.

The only change is we replaced a ceiling chandelier yesterday.  It has radio bulbs in it, the previous one had LED.  Everything worked fine yesterday and a little this morning, then poof.

The other LED light works just fine.  These three lights are on the same circuit.

Comment: What are "radio bulbs" ? Is that a metaphorical "Poof" or a physical noise poof ?

Comment: If you put one of the radio bulbs in question in a known-good table lamp, does that bulb work?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be electrical noise.  I've seen this with LED bulbs before.  LED's tend to want clean power.

If you take the bulbs out of the working fixture and turn the chandelier off, do the bulbs in the flickering fixture stabilize?   Does the chandelier have a dimmer on it?

If you take the bulbs out of the flickering fixture and put them in a regular table lamp, do they still flicker?

Of course, bad wiring in the flickering fixture can also cause trouble.  ie. Perhaps a wire nut is loose, etc.

The idea here is to rule out variables one by one until you find the problem.